# Delphi - Wrong data writing then reading using BlockWrite/BlockRead

Tags: delphi

Delphi Tokyo - I and creating a configuration file.  I am writing the config file using BlockWrite, then reading it using BlockRead.  Something is wrong when I am reading a String.  I am getting what appears to be asian characters...

I think the issue is with the way I am defining my ReadString routine.

Here is my WriteString routine

```
  procedure WriteString(s: ShortString);
  begin { WriteString }
    BlockWrite(fil, s, succ(length(s)));
  end; { WriteString }
```

My ReadString Routine should give me back the same data, but it is not.
Here is the ReadString Code.

```
 function ReadString: string;
  var
    count: Cardinal;
    l: integer;
  begin
    BlockRead(fil, l, sizeof(integer), count);
    SetLength(Result, l);
    BlockRead(fil, Result[1], l, count);
  end;
```

The first value read from the config file is a Boolean, and it appears to be read the file properly.  The next value is a string, and is messed up.  Any help appreciated.

Here is the FULL WriteConfig and ReadConfig Routine, as well as a SetConfigValues which just creates some test data.

```
procedure SetConfigValues;
begin
  //
  gCMD_Globals.Load_Table := True;
  gCMD_Globals.DB_Tablename := 'my Test Table';
  gCMD_Globals.Create_Backup := True;
  gCMD_Globals.Delete_Existing_Backup := False;
  gCMD_Globals.Truncate_Existing_Table := True;

  SetLength(gCMD_Detail, 2);

  gCMD_Detail[0].CommandType := 'CMD1';
  gCMD_Detail[0].P1 := 'P11';
  gCMD_Detail[0].P2 := 'P21';
  gCMD_Detail[0].P3 := 'P31';

  gCMD_Detail[1].CommandType := 'CMD1';
  gCMD_Detail[1].P1 := 'P12';
  gCMD_Detail[1].P2 := 'P22';
  gCMD_Detail[1].P3 := 'P32';

end;


procedure WriteConfigFile(FileName: string);
var
  fil: file;
  i: integer;
  num: word; { allows up to 65535 records }
const
  ver: byte = LatestFileVersion;

  procedure WriteString(s: ShortString);
  begin { WriteString }
    BlockWrite(fil, s, succ(length(s)));
  end; { WriteString }

begin { WriteConfigFile }
  assignFile(fil, FileName);
  rewrite(fil, 1); { Create the file }
  BlockWrite(fil, ver, sizeof(ver)); { Write the file version }

  // Now we need to write the gCMD_Globals record
  with gCMD_Globals do
  begin { write the data }

    BlockWrite(fil, Load_Table, sizeof(Load_Table));
    WriteString(DB_Tablename);
    BlockWrite(fil, Create_Backup, sizeof(Create_Backup));
    BlockWrite(fil, Delete_Existing_Backup, sizeof(Delete_Existing_Backup));
    BlockWrite(fil, Truncate_Existing_Table, sizeof(Truncate_Existing_Table));
  end;

  num := length(gCMD_Detail);
  BlockWrite(fil, num, sizeof(num)); { Write the number of records }
  for i := 0 to high(gCMD_Detail) do
    with gCMD_Detail[i] do
    begin { write the data }
      WriteString(CommandType);
      WriteString(P1);
      WriteString(P2);
      WriteString(P3);
    end; { with }
  CloseFile(fil);
end; { WriteConfigFile }

procedure ReadConfigFile(FileName: string);
var
  fil: file;
  i: integer;
  num: word; { allows up to 65535 records }
  ver: byte;

  function ReadString: string;
  var
    count: Cardinal;
    l: integer;
  begin
    BlockRead(fil, l, sizeof(integer), count);
    SetLength(Result, l);
    BlockRead(fil, Result[1], l, count);
  end;


begin { ReadFile }
  assignFile(fil, FileName);
  reset(fil, 1); { Open the file }
  BlockRead(fil, ver, sizeof(ver)); { Read the file version }

  // Now we need to write the gCMD_Globals record
  with gCMD_Globals do
  begin { write the data }

    BlockRead(fil, Load_Table, sizeof(Load_Table));
    DB_Tablename := ReadString;
    BlockRead(fil, Create_Backup, sizeof(Create_Backup));
    BlockRead(fil, Delete_Existing_Backup, sizeof(Delete_Existing_Backup));
    BlockRead(fil, Truncate_Existing_Table, sizeof(Truncate_Existing_Table));
  end;

  BlockRead(fil, num, sizeof(num)); { Read the number of records }
  SetLength(gCMD_Detail, num);
  for i := 0 to high(gCMD_Detail) do
    with gCMD_Detail[i] do
    begin { Read the data }
      CommandType := ReadString;
      P1 := ReadString;
      P2 := ReadString;
      P3 := ReadString;
    end; { with }
  CloseFile(fil);
end; { ReadConfigFile }
```

Comment: It's 2018. Why are you still Pascal IO and  ANSI? It would be so much easier for you to use, for example, JSON and be able to support Unicode and not have to write manual parsing code. I have no interest in telling you how to fix this code. My strong advice is to throw it away and use something more modern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ShortString` is an 8-bit string type that uses a 1-byte length. You are writing the `ShortString` to file correctly (assuming the file's "record" size has been set to 1 beforehand), but you are not reading it back correctly. You are reading a 4-byte `integer` instead of a 1-byte `AnsiChar`/`Byte` for the string length, and then you are reading 8-bit characters into a 16-bit `UnicodeString` instead of into a `ShortString`.

Use this instead:

```
function ReadString: string;
var
  len: Byte;
  s: ShortString;
begin
  BlockRead(fil, len, 1);
  SetLength(s, len);
  BlockRead(fil, s[1], len);
  Result := string(s);
end;
```

I would not recommend using a `ShortString` at all, though. You are using a Unicode version of Delphi, so if you are free to change the file layout, I would suggest making `WriteString()` take a `(Unicode)String` as input and convert it to UTF-8 for storage, then make `ReadString()` do the reverse, eg:

```
procedure WriteString(const s: UnicodeString);
var
  utf: UTF8String;
  len: integer;
begin
  utf := UTF8String(s);
  len := Length(utf);
  BlockWrite(fil, len, sizeof(len));
  BlockWrite(fil, PAnsiChar(utf)^, len);
end;

function ReadString: UnicodeString;
var
  len: integer;
  utf: UTF8String;
begin
  BlockRead(fil, len, sizeof(len));
  SetLength(utf, len);
  BlockRead(fil, PAnsiChar(utf)^, len);
  Result := UnicodeString(utf);
end;
```

Comment: SetLength(utf, len); raises an out of memory error, because len = a huge number,. The above does not appear to be valid code, or is very situational.

Comment: @T.S that means either the file read pointer was not at the correct offset when reading the length, or the code was maybe trying to read an old ShortString based file.

Answer (score 1):

For shortstrings the length is ord(s[0]) and only one byte is written. But you read four bytes into l. So you cannot expect this to work. As a fix, you can blockwrite the length as integer or blockread a byte variable l.